# Fitting a curve in MATLAB using lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit data with MATLAB using the lsqcurvefit function, but I'm having some trouble.
MATLAB gives me the following message.

```
Local minimum possible.

lsqcurvefit stopped because the size of the current step is less than
the selected value of the step size tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>

Optimization stopped because the norm of the current step, 5.578610e-021,
is less than options.TolX = 1.000000e-020.

Optimization Metric                                 Options
norm(step) =  5.58e-021                      TolX =  1e-020 (selected)
```

I've tried changing TolX and TolFun but the only thing that has changed, is the program now takes ages to finish.

The function I'm trying to fit is this:

```
function P = dIdV(delta, E, T)

%delta in eV
%E in eV
%T in K

gamma = 0.00001;

%IV curve
arr = zeros(size(E));
A = -E(length(E))*10:E(length(E))/750:E(length(E))*10;

for i=1:length(E)
    arr(i) = trapz(A, (FermiDirac(-E(i)+A, T) - FermiDirac(A,T)) .* SCDOS(-E(i)+A, delta, gamma));
end

%derivative
B = zeros(size(E));
points = 49;
for i=1:length(E)-points
    p = polyfit(E(i:i+points), arr(i:i+points), 1);
    B(floor(points/2)+i-1) = p(1);
end

%vector size back to original
for k=0:ceil(points/2)
    B(k+1) = B(floor(points/2));
    B(length(E)-k) = B(length(E)-ceil(points/2)-1);
end

P = B
```

FermiDirac is

```
function P=FermiDirac(E,T)

%E in eV
%T in Kelvin

kb=8.617343*10^(-5);

P=1./(1+exp(E./(kb.*T)));
```

SCDOS is

```
function N=SCDOS(E,delta,gamma)

%E in eV
%delta in eV
%gamma undefined

N=abs(real((E-1i*gamma)./sqrt((E-1i*gamma).^2-delta^2)));
```

What I'm calculating is the dI/dV curve for a superconductor at some temperature T. I'm supposed to get a value for the energy gap (delta) through fitting.

I would post my data here, but it's 10000 points long, so I'm not sure how to post it. I've tried filtering my data to smooth the curve, but to no avail. I've also tried using different intervals.

Any suggestions on how to make this work are welcome. Better ways to fit are also welcome.

EDIT: [Here's a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KoCo.png) of the data. The blue line is the derivative of the data as calculated in the function above, the red line is the filtered data and the green line is the theoretical curve. I'm trying to fit the red one to the green one.

Comment: How close is the initialization? Do you have any plots you can show?

Comment: I added a link to the graph. The initialization should be very close. We expect a value of around 0.001.

Comment: It appears that it fits the central part of the curve very well and just doesn't bring the curve down fast enough at the edges. Have you tried any other fitting functions? I only have experience with [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) and [simulannealbnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/minimization-using-simulated-annealing-algorithm.html). fminsearch gets caught in local minima while simulated annealing is very good at getting a global minima of a bounded problem. It seems that the function is caught in a local minimum as it mentions.

Comment: The only other alternative to trying other fitting functions is to write your own method such as [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

Comment: I think I'm gonna try those two. I'm not sure if fminsearch is gonna work though, because it's pretty much the same as lsqcurvefit except I'd still have to take the sum of the difference between the data points and the theoretical curve.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried just fitting from x-values -0.8 to 0.8 and it still gave me the same message, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Also be aware that at least fminsearch (and probably lsqcurvefit) use the initialization value of the parameters to scale the step size. I have run into problems when fitting a parameter that has a large range, starts very small. The step size never allows it to cover the full range. So in that case initializing further away with that parameter will provide a better result. You can also "trick" matlab to making the step size bigger. multiply your paramater by 1e4 or so and then divide by the same value before calculating the function.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work now. Any idea on how I can get the error on the parameters?

Comment: If you're still using lsqcurvefit it's `[x,resnorm,residual] = lsqcurvefit(...)` See [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/residual-analysis.html) Essentially residual is code for error in statistical speak. So resnorm is the overall sum of squared errors of the fit and residual is the error at each point.